# Fetching data properly with Futurebuilder and json response

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

How can I render my response in my text widget?

My json snapshot.data is as following:

```
"{\"0\":{\"Breed\":\"American Hairless Terrier\",\"count\":1},\"1\":{\"Breed\":\"Bolognese\",\"count\":2},\"2\":{\"Breed\":\"Cavalier King Charles Spaniel\",\"count\":12},\"3\":{\"Breed\":\"Central Asian Shepherd Dog\",\"count\":1},\"4\":{\"Breed\":\"Papillon\",\"count\":1}}"
```

I tried to display my data like this:

```
Text(snapshot.data[index.toString()]['Breed']),
```

but I am getting:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

Comment: Does `print(snapshot.data[0]['Breed']);` output 'American Hairless Terrier'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, might not be perfect but i will give you some idea, the error is because you are assigning int value to Text widget

```
Text((snapshot.data[index]. 
  ['Breed']).toString());
 
     
 if you want to show it in 
  futureBuilder and listview 
   here:

    FutureBuilder(
       future: FirebaseFirestore. 
        instance.
       collection("groups").
       doc(groupId).snapshots(),
      //here your collection name 
       // and doc id
       builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  return Text("Loading");
}
var userDocument = snapshot.data["Breeds"];
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: userDocument.length,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Text(userDocument[index]);
         ),
  }
```

);

Answer (score 1):

The indices 0,1,2,3.. are strings(wrapped with quotation marks). But you are providing int.
Try

```
Text(snapshot.data['Breed'][index.toString()])
```

Comment: I edited my question with some modifications. I  am still having this issue trying your solution index.toString()

Comment: can you share some more of the code you tried